# Filter Lock Missing on Default Report Filters

Tags: lightning, filters, custom-reports

If I create a new report with report type "Oppportunities", the default filters Show Me, Close Date, Territories, Opportunity Status and Probability cannot be locked. If I add new filters, these can be locked. Is there a way to lock the default filters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer is 'No' you cannot lock default report filters.  You might want to review [Idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003fVdQAI) link and vote for this feature.

Thanks